# Get SQL Server 2008 database settings list

Tags: sql-server-2008, codeigniter

i read alot of users that posted their database settings and they look like this:

```
$db['local']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';  
$db['local']['dbprefix'] = '';  
$db['local']['pconnect'] = FALSE;  
$db['local']['db_debug'] = TRUE;  
$db['local']['cache_on'] = FALSE;  
$db['local']['cachedir'] = '';  
$db['local']['char_set'] = 'utf8';  
$db['local']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';  
$db['local']['swap_pre'] = '';  
$db['local']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
```

I use Sql Server 2008, how can i see those settings of my database? what is the command?

Comment: This seems to be more to do with your programming language and connection library than with SQL Server. If you add the tags for those things, you may get an answer.

Comment: you are rght, i made a mistake, these properties are of the codeigniter, not SQL Server properties. sorry :)